# Problem in deleting data in windows form

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2008, sql-server-ce, dotnetnuke

```
    public static void deletePersonInfo(int number)
    {
        SqlCeConnection sqlConn = null;
        SqlCeCommand cmdDelete;

        try
        {
            sqlConn = new SqlCeConnection(databaseString);
            sqlConn.Open();

            cmdDelete = new SqlCeCommand("DELETE FROM PersonInfo WHERE Number = @numb", sqlConn);
            cmdDelete.Parameters.Add(new SqlCeParameter("@numb", SqlDbType.Int)).Value = number;
            cmdDelete.ExecuteNonQuery();

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            if (sqlConn != null)
            {
                sqlConn.Close();
            }
        }

    }
```

Thats my code for deleting a member. It runs fine without any errors. I also checked whether the correct value is being passed. and yes it is.
The method receives the correct member number, does not give any error, executes successfully, but does not make any change in the database.

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with this code.

Comment: how do i do that adrian. if you can send me some helpful links it would be really appreciated

Comment: Are you talking to me? My name's Michael :-). If you're using plain old SQL Server, run SQL Profiler, which should be included in your SQL Server install. I think it's in the Tools menu in Workbench. If you're running something specific to SQL CE, then I can't help, no experience there.

Answer (score 1):

Check  the return value of " cmdDelete.ExecuteNonQuery(); " whether it is returning non zero value or not.
if value is nonzero then only database will be modify.

Answer (score 0):

Does your connection string implement security?  Try and look at the event log or in the permissions for the table.  It may make a successful connection to the database but not have proper permissions to make the change.  If you are an admin or domain admin you should have access by default.  So you might also need to check that the domain admin group was added to the sql server box.

Comment: I am a newbie to this. How do I check the log to see permissions for the table. This is a personal project and is on my personal system itself.

Answer (score 0):

You may have more copies of your database file while debugging - see this: http://erikej.blogspot.com/2010/05/faq-why-does-my-changes-not-get-saved.html